# charts for iphone or html5

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, graph, charts

i am working on iphone project that require to display data in charts.

the most important is design of chart to be good looking.

if html5 i need to be off-line as application will be off-line.

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question - this topic has already been covered in some detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The best chart tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Answer (score 1):

> the most important is design of chart to be good looking.

I would recommend using [Morris](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js)

Reasons:

1. The charts are looking excellent based on other charts that are on the market
2. Its free (Simplified BSD License)
3. It works fine on Chrome, IE8+, FireFox, Opera, Safari
4. It works fine iOS 3+, Android 3+
5. It's lightweight 26.3 KB
6. It requires jQuery >=1.7 & Raphaël >=2.0
7. It's dead simple to integrate & use.

Answer (score 0):

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) should do the trick. Renders Charts in HTML5 Canvas as well as/or SVG.